# Javascript - Growth Rate in a field - Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

I need a help with this javascript above;

In my context, i have a Data Extension (named: CountsDE2)that is populate via integration. I lookup a report that I can accompany the growth rate by 
daily this Data Extension;
In my searchs the better method is create a Data Extension and populate this via query and after use a javascript to have my growth rate.

The Query it's normally, but the javascript not working. [image]

```
<script runat="server">

var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('CountsDE2', 'Counts','Hour DESC',['Secret'],[1]);


if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {

var today = dataRows[0]["Hour"]; //Sets the most recent date
var num1 = dataRows[0]["Count"]; //Sets the most recent count entry
var num2 = dataRows[1]["Count"]; //Sets the previous count entry
}

var growthRaw = (num2 / num1) * 100;
var growth = (growthRaw).toFixed(2) + '%';

var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("CountsDE2",["Hour"], [today],["Growth"],[growth]);

</script>
```

Comment: can you give some insight into how it is 'not working'.

Comment: did i just do the exact same edit like you @Gortonington? :D

Comment: Fastest edits in the west *spins guns*

Comment: Hello @Gortonington, 
Happens a errored that Automation Studio does not get me the details, but i changed the declaration of Server-Side JavaScript Block to "
<script runat=server language="JavaScript" executioncontexttype="post">" and now does not appears error, but the script simply does nothing.

Comment: the error is likely happening since there is only 1 entry in your DE. The script requires at least 2 records.

Comment: also since you are storing the count as text, it may need to be formatted into an int again before the JS can do math on it. You can try `parseInt()` or `Number()`

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, which is actually inaccurate data in the SFMC SSJS LookupOrderedRows() documentation.  The second parameter should be the number of rows you want to look up, not 'the field you want to retrieve' like the documentation says.

See below for corrected SSJS (I have tested it and it produced expected results)

```
<script runat="server">

var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows('CountsDE2', 2,'Hour DESC',['Secret'],[1]);


if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {

var today = dataRows[0]["Hour"]; //Sets the most recent date
var num1 = dataRows[0]["Counts"]; //Sets the most recent count entry
var num2 = dataRows[1]["Counts"]; //Sets the previous count entry
}

var growthRaw = (num2 / num1) * 100;
var growth = (growthRaw).toFixed(2) + '%';

var rows = Platform.Function.UpdateData("CountsDE2",["Hour"], [today],["Growth"],[growth]);

</script>
```

Comment: Hello, @Gortinington! You are awesome, simply fantastic!